# Youtube ENTIRELY crashes the computer

Tags: youtube

About a week ago a regular Synaptic update ran in the background. Ever since, when I try to watch a Youtube video (just hitting "play" on the video) the monitor goes black for a moment, then there are just random bars of colour flashing. The only way to fix it is to turn the computer off using the power button and then restarting the computer. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. It looks like a lot of people have had troubles since that update (red videos, videos that just don't work) but I haven't found anybody with this kind of spectacular crash. I've tried both Firefox and Chromium, same results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! I disabled the Youtube cookie and it DOES work now. It means I can't log in to Youtube, but since I don't even have an account, I don't care. Details here: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/fix-pinkred-youtube-videos-bug-using.html

Answer (score 3):

It might be a flash plugin. For Google chrome there is a build in flash plugin. Try to install another one and activate it. In your web browser type

> about:plugins

and choose *details*. There should be an option to activate/deactivate any of your plugins.

Comment: Thank you! I disabled the flash plugin, in Chromium, then uninstalled and reinstalled it, then enabled it again. Everything works beautifully now.

Comment: Hmm. I spoke too soon. When I restarted Chromium, the Youtube problem happened again. I can play Vimeo videos, no problem.